# Magento2 - Customer Session set one store to another store

Tags: magento2, multistore, customer-session

Magento2  - I have setup 2 store like

```
        1: default store view (home page)
        2: English ( sub pages )
```

When I'm going to English store than login its working and get customer session but when i'm going to home page (default store view) than session is getting NULL.